# How to access .bashrc file from Java code

Tags: java, linux, bash, filepath, filereader

There is a specific path that I need to obtain from my .bashrc file to be used in my Java code.  So I need to read in the .bashrc, however I am unsure of the path or if I am even approaching this correctly.

Here is the code I am trying

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("~/.bashrc));
while(reader.ready()) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    //operations
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fully qualified path instead of "~" to get to your home directory.  ~ is expanded by the shell, and Java doesn't expand that for you.  You can use the system property "user.home" to get to your home directory.

Code example:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")), ".bashrc")));
for(String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine())
    //operations
}
```

Comment: +1 for using correct 2-argument File constructor instead of concatenating the path

Comment: As usual for StackOverflow, I'd like to know why the anonymous downvoter chose to downvote this answer.  At least tell me why, so that I can make the answer better.